# Is it possible to count a text string inside a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2003, is it possible to count the number of commas in a cell containing the text.
For example cell A1 contains the text
a,b,c,d,e,f,
In cell A2 I would like to display the number of commas present in A1, that is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a formula like this:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))
```

This gets the length of A1, then takes A1 and removes all the commas, and returns the difference. In your case, 6.